# Excluding a specific page from Spring Security that is redirected from login page

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I am having trouble while I am redirecting an authentication link from my login page. I added the link in to my login page in JSF like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="pageToRedirect.xhtml">Login via Testinium Cloud</a>
</div>
```

My spring security configuration is like this:

```
and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(DEFAULT_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/jsfPages/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/errorPages/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(jsfAccessDeniedHandler())
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jsfAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage(LOGIN_PAGE).permitAll()
                .failureUrl(LOGIN_PAGE).permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl(DEFAULT_URL)
                .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl(LOGOUT_URL).permitAll()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error/403.xhtml");
```

How could I redirect my link from login page without gettin an authentication error. I tried

```
    @Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/signup");
}
```

But it didn't work out for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude a page from your spring security configuration without overriding web security, you can add 'not' method that is connected to 'antMatchers' method in your code with authenticated() method following like this:

```
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(DEFAULT_URL).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/jsfPages/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/errorPages/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(LOGIN_TESTINIUM).not().authenticated()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
```